# How is that possible for Priscilla to kill Teresa?

Tags: claymore

I read the manga and watch the anime. It was awesome, but in only one place it doesn't make sense at all. When Priscilla killed Teresa.

I know, Priscilla was no 2 and she was too powerful, and she's got awakened in that second. But still we are talking about Teresa! Her best ability was that she could read the moves of her opponent. right?

Comment: i can't remember correctly but didn't Prescilla Yoki surge to the level where she would become an Awakened Being when she went and killed Teressa?

Comment: @Memor-X yes, but that is my case. Teressa could sense every movement of her opponent. she could sense that Prescilla is comming https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f_f01KD07uc

Comment: Also in manga, when Clare awakened and became Teressa, she could beat Precilla (although she couldn't kill her unless she awakened her-selves)  so she had to be able to survive the first attack

Comment: if i recall correctly Clare only defeated Precilla because she awakened (not fully but close) while Teressa to my knowledge never partially awakened. also i'm not entire sure how much experience Teressa has against Awakened Beings and not sure how effective her abilities would be against them. it's possible that Teressa's ability to sense every movement wasn't enough against an awakened Precilla and was caught off guard. ofcause it's been some time since i've seen the anime and i haven't read the manga

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Memor-X was right, when Priscilla killed Teresa, Priscilla was already in an awakened state. It's true that Teresa could read the movement of her opponent because Teresa can sense the strength and speed of yoma energy flowing through her opponent's body. However, when Teresa fought Priscilla, Teresa couldn't read her movements because there was too much yoma power coming from all over Priscilla's body.

Claymore Chapter 22, Marked For Death 5, Page 26

[image: Claymore Chapter 22, Marked For Death 5, Page 26]

But of course, Teresa was still able to match her. She was using just enough yoma power for her eye color to change to counter Priscilla. However, when Priscilla passed her limit, she begged for Teresa to kill her and Teresa turned back to her normal state, seeing Priscilla on her knees. At this point Teresa probably couldn't read Priscilla's movements and let her guard down for a moment leading to Priscilla being able to kill her.

In [your comment](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/36055/claymore-how-is-that-possible-for-prescilla-to-kill-teressa#comment48478_36055), it's true that when Clare awakened and became Teresa, she could beat Priscilla. However, Teresa was that strong only because of Clare's feelings toward Teresa.

from Claymore final chapter, Last Scene, Page 7

[image: Claymore Last Scene Page 7]

Answer (score 0):

Teresa wasn't as focused as she normally would've been because Clare made her a bit soft. Her friend even said the old Teresa would've killed Priscilla when she was lying there crying. The old Teresa wouldn't have let it get that far.